# Web Api Error Handling Filter Exception's Response property not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created an error handling filter for an ASP.NET Web Api application where I'm trying to intercept all transport-related errors handled by ASP.NET pipeline. I'm extending the base `ExceptionFilterAttribute` class and overriding the `OnException` method.

What I'm trying to do is first check if the Exception passed in has a response already and then construct a generic response object using the status code, etc. The `OnException` method looks as follows...

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext ctx)
        {
            log.Error(ctx.Exception.Message, ctx.Exception);

            if (ctx.Exception.Response.IsNotNull())
            {
                ctx.Response = ApiResponseFactory.CreateErrorResponse(ctx.Response.StatusCode
                    , ctx.Response.ReasonPhrase, ctx.Exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response = ApiResponseFactory.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                    , "server_error"
                    , ctx.Exception);
            }
        }
```

All that `ApiResponseFactory.CreateErrorResponse` method does is construct a response object, nothing fancy. Now, the problem I'm having is that the `Response` property of the context's exception is not defined (`ctx.Exception.Response`)...I'm obviously missing a `using` statement but with all the extension assemblies that comes with MVC, Web Api and other NuGet packages I'm finding hard to know which "using statement" and/or assembly and/or packages I should be referencing...and I thought the [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) problem of the 90's was resolved. Here are the using statements that I'm referencing in this code file...

```
using log4net;
using Stems.API.Base.Plumbing;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
```

and here are the NuGet packages...

```
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

So, the question is...**How can I get a reference to the `Response` property of the context's Exception?**

#### Update based on @cableroad's answer

There IS a `Response` property on the `Exception` property. See one of the exceptions I'm getting below...

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
> the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this

[image: Debugger screenshot]

> exception for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was right in front of my eyes. For some reason I completely missed that the `Exception` property was of type `System.Exception`, however, the underlying type assigned to that property is of type `System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException`. That said, all I needed to do was casting it to the correct type...

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext ctx)
{
    log.Error(ctx.Exception.Message, ctx.Exception);
    var ex = ctx.Exception as HttpResponseException;

    if(ex.IsNotNull() && ex.Response.IsNotNull())
    {
        ctx.Response = ApiResponseFactory.CreateErrorResponse(ex.Response.StatusCode
                   , ex.Response.ReasonPhrase, ex.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.Response = ApiResponseFactory.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                , "server_error"
                , ctx.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad that it was resolved..i thought of that as well (especially when i saw that it didnt have a response property..) but later found that your exception was actually a HttpResponseException.

Answer (score 1):

There is no response property within HttpActionExecutedContext.Exception.

You should do this check instead

```
if (ctx.Exception!=null)
```

Comment: I just updated my question showing that there seems to be a `Response` object on that Exception property

Comment: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception(v=vs.118).aspx) it is...